# Ponteiro de struct em C

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct, alocação

O que acontece é o seguinte, dentro da função `ins_ult()` eu consigo alterar o valor de `root->data`, mas fora da função o valor permanece `NULL`.
Estou passando o parametro de forma errada ou usando o `malloc` incorretamente?

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct Node_t{
        void *data;
        struct Node_t *next;
}Node;
int main(){
        Node *root;
        root=NULL;
        ins_ult(root,100);
        printf("%d,%d\n",root->data);
}
void ins_ult(Node *root, void *data){
        if(root == NULL){
                root = malloc(sizeof(Node));
                root->data = data;
                root->next = 0;
                printf("%d\n",root->data);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voce nao altera `root` na funcao. Voce precisa que ela receba um ponteiro para um ponteiro do tipo Node para que o valor nao se perca depois que a funcao retorne.

Esse codigo:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct node{
  void *data;
  struct node *next;
};

void ins_ult(struct node **root, void *data){
  if(*root == NULL){
    *root = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node *));
    (*root)->data = data;
    (*root)->next = 0;
    printf("%d\n", (*root)->data);
  }
}

int main(){
  struct node *root;
  root=NULL;
  ins_ult(&root, 100);
  printf("%d\n", root->data);
  return 0;
}
```

vai imprimir `100` duas vezes na tela.